# Google test macro

Tags: c++, googletest

I am curious if there is a macro defined for the google test framework which allows me to test if the code is compiled as part of a test, or not. I am interested to achieve the following behaviour:

```
int someFunction()
{
    // do some stuff and some checks
    if(i_am_not_happy_with_results_above)
    {
    #if CODE_COMPILED_AS_PART_OF_TEST
        FAIL()
    #else
        exit();
    #endif
    }
    return 42;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned above, there is no such thing in Google Test, but you can achieve this by defining preprocessor token, just add `-DCODE_COMPILED_AS_PART_OF_TEST` to your build command to build in test mode. For example,

```
g++ -DCODE_COMPILED_AS_PART_OF_TEST source.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `std::system` function from `stdlib.h` to run your `make` for the code-build and then test the returned value from `make` to see if it was successful.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such thing, because that is not what unit tests are for. They tests run-time functionality. If you include or remove some code, ideally unit tests should fail <sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>Doesn't always happen, depending on the code.</sub>

Comment: That did not answer the question. There are many reasons to test whether unit tests are in effect. Exposing private interfaces to allow test input injection is a very good reason to know if unit tests are in effect.